# PHP code contextual filter (arguments)

Tags: 7, views

I try to display a list of content with exposed filter in Drupal 7 and Views 3, I create a page and it works, but I also want to display a map with the filter, so I create a block for the gmap and for get the information about the filter I add a contextual filter with php code like this (where province is the name of the field)

```
return $_GET["province"];
```

In Drupal 6 it works this method, but in Drupal 7 I receive this error

> Notice: Undefined index: province in eval() (line 1 of /pathtomodule/views/plugins/views_plugin_argument_default_php.inc(49) : eval()'d code).

So where is the error, I return only one argument (I know that I need some control if the code is null, but in this case I )

Comment: Did you check the parameter is passed through the URL? Is AJAX enabled for that view?

Comment: Thanks, i try to enable ajax and disable but there are no change, the same error, the views is a block, because i use data module and for the exposed filter need a page, yes the parameter is passed correct from the url, i also try with this code:

if isset($_GET["distance[search_distance]"]) {
return $_GET["distance[search_distance]"];
} else {
return "100";
}

But i receive:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in location_handler_argument_location_proximity->query() (line 119 of ...

Answer (score 1):

> `Notice: Undefined index: province in eval() (line 1 of /pathtomodule/views/plugins/views_plugin_argument_default_php.inc(49) : eval()'d code).`

This error occurs when the array key `province` does not exist. The PHP documentation goes into greater detail - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses the same variable name... **E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized variables**, however not in the case of appending elements to the uninitialized array. **isset() language construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already initialized.**

Instead of

`return $_GET["province"];`

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) logic. Also, you shouldn't be directly accessing $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST; best practice is to use [drupal_get_query_parameters()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_query_parameters/7)

```
$param = drupal_get_query_parameters();
if (isset($param['province'])) {
  return $param['province'];
}
return NULL;
```

To address the problem in your comment:

> But i receive: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in `location_handler_argument_location_proximity->query()`

This is (for all intrinsic purposes) the same as the undefined index; `location_handler_argument_location_proximity->query()` is expecting an array with at least two elements (offset 0 and 1), and that method expected, but did not receive an array with two elements. It might not even be getting an array.